# what does command! Maketags do in vim?

Tags: vim

In this video [Vim tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM) at **19:50** in `.vimrc` mentioned

```
command! MakeTags !ctags -R .
```

What does this do? Even without this statement my `ctags -R .` command is working correctly and I am able to traverse across multiple hierarchies.

Comment: `:help :command`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are defining a command `MakeTags` (the ! overrides existing commands called MakeTags). Using ! calls `ctags -R` in a shell. ctags generates tags and -R is the recusive flag.